# VBA Macro to filter, copy the specified value from a column and create then paste in a new sheet with that column name

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA macro. I coded the macro below that filters on column "N" containing "Ocean" and copies its corresponding data. Then it creates a new worksheet with the name "Ocean" and pastes the data there.

Or is it possible to filter on column N containing "Ocean" and delete the non-matching data? Please help. Below is my code and excel screenshot for reference.

```
Dim Wf As Workbook
Dim Tsht As Worksheet, FSht As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long, lRw As Long

Set Wf = ActiveWorkbook
Set Tsht = Wf.Sheets("Main")

With Tsht
        lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


Set FSht = Wf.Sheets("Ocean")

    With FSht
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A" & lRw).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Ocean"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy

      End With
```

[image: Column N]

I want the macro to only split rows containing Ocean in a new sheet, with a sheet name of "Ocean". Or macro should keep only data corresponding to Ocean and delete the rest... Please help...........

Comment: I think answer to this would be based on your data set. How many rows are you expecting in the sheet? Reason why I ask that is because generally it is advisable to delete rows from bottom up. But if you have over 500k+ rows in the sheet this can take some time. Plus if you are using filter this approach won't work. So you could use an Array approach (get your data in an array, remove from array and set it back in your sheet). Again if you have large data set, you might want to consider a combination of Array and `Range.Find` approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AutoFilter Copy

This will delete the worksheet `Ocean` if it exists. Then it will add a new sheet, name it `Ocean` and copy the filtered data from worksheet `Main` to it.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilterCopy()

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ' If the code is in the ActiveWorkbook you should use ThisWorkbook instead.
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
    ' Delete Target Worksheet.
    Dim FSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets("Ocean")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        FSht.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    FSht.Name = "Ocean"
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim Tsht As Worksheet
    Set Tsht = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    With Tsht
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        ' 14 is column N
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Ocean"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy FSht.Range("A1")
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Worksheet created, data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

EDIT:

- Instead of column `N` (14), OP wants to identify the criteria column with its header: "Mode".

**Edited Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFilterCopy()

    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    ' If the code is in the ActiveWorkbook you should use ThisWorkbook instead.
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        
    ' Delete Target Worksheet.
    Dim FSht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets("Ocean")
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        FSht.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Define Target Worksheet.
    Set FSht = wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count))
    FSht.Name = "Ocean"
    
    ' Define Source Worksheet.
    Dim Tsht As Worksheet
    Set Tsht = wb.Worksheets("Main")
    With Tsht
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
        Const FieldName As String = "Mode"
        Dim FieldNumber As Long
        ' Note that there will be an error if "Mode" cannot be found.
        FieldNumber = Application.Match(FieldName, .Rows(1), 0)
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=FieldNumber, Criteria1:="Ocean"
        .AutoFilter.Range.Copy FSht.Range("A1")
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Worksheet created, data copied.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is Perfect! Thanks a lot @VBasic2008... Appreciate your help.... thanks again.

Comment: Is there any chance that we can put column name "Mode" instead of 14 just in case if column varies there won't be any error. 
 14 is column N
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Ocean"

Comment: @JaySameer: I've added another version as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `Range.Find`. I generally try to avoid hard coding rows and columns whenever possible. You will see where I've searched the header row for "Mode". This allows the column order to change without breaking the code.

I would modify my code after seeing the answer provided by @VBasic2008. I would use the `.AutoFilter.Copy` method, rather than looping through each match. I also like how he has checked to see if a sheet with the desired mode already exists.

Good luck!

```
Public Sub ExtractDataByMode()

Const mode = "Ocean"

Dim mainWS As Worksheet
Set mainWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
Dim hdrRow As Range
Set hdrRow = Intersect(mainWS.Rows(1), mainWS.UsedRange)

Dim modeColIdx As Integer
modeColIdx = hdrRow.Find(What:="Mode", lookat:=xlWhole, _
    MatchCase:=False).Column
    
Dim modeColRng As Range
Set modeColRng = Intersect(mainWS.Columns(modeColIdx), mainWS.UsedRange)

Dim firstMatch As Range
Set firstMatch = modeColRng.Find(What:=mode, lookat:=xlWhole, _
    MatchCase:=False)
    
Dim modeWS As Worksheet
Set modeWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add( _
    After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets( _
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
modeWS.Name = mode
hdrRow.Copy modeWS.Cells(1, 1)

Dim match As Range
Dim nextRow As Integer
Dim matchRow As Range
Set match = firstMatch
nextRow = modeWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
Do
    Set matchRow = Intersect(mainWS.Rows(match.Row), mainWS.UsedRange)
    matchRow.Copy modeWS.Cells(nextRow, 1)
    Set match = modeColRng.FindNext(match)
    nextRow = modeWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

Loop While match.Address <> firstMatch.Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks @BoilermakerRV

Comment: Hi, It creates a new sheet named ocean correctly .... but immediately after when it proceeds on the further loop it  becomes too slow  to perform or in next looping, it takes 2 -3 mins

Comment: the above code is working fine but after this module is over it hangs for about 4-5 mins and then loops further

Comment: It tested fine for me, but with only 28 rows of randomly generated integers. I think the `.AutoFilter.Copy` option might be better performing with a larger data set.

Comment: Or is it possible like instead of creating a new sheet named "Ocean"! It selects the value from column mode as "Ocean" and deletes rest all data and keeps only data corresponding to mode ocean in same "Main" sheet.